# Salesforce CLI - Issues Testing in Non-scratch Orgs

Tags: apex, unit-test, salesforcedx

Working in a large org with a significant amount of Apex. Goal is to run a singular test and get a code coverage report back in Visual Studio Code. I do not particularly care the path do so. I am testing in a Sandbox, not a Dev Hub or Scratch org.

What i have tried is utilizing the CLI and crafting a line that looks like this:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run --tests BatchFileDeleteTest.test --resultformat human --codecoverage --synchronous -u MySandbox
```

The issue was that this did not just run the BatchFileDeleteTest but rather every test in my org/sandbox, which took a significant amount of time. Also the test coverage report was every test. I'm not trying to get code coverage for every test but rather just the what the batchfiledeletetest.test method covers. Is this possible?

EDIT: Looks like it is possible but was not before https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_sf_cli_code_coverage_apextests.htm

I'll create a seperate question for setting or updating Environment Variables

Comment: Can you show the `=== Test Summary` for this test run (personal info redacted, of course)?

Comment: I think that the link i put in answers the question. Without the SFDX_IMPROVED_CODE_COVERAGE environment variable set, it will pull all code coverage for all classes. I am running into issues setting that environment variable (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303335/setting-environment-variables-in-salesforce-dx) if you have any ideas

Comment: Still, you should have only seen that one class execute. Using the new environment variable reduces the clutter at the top, but the test results should still have been for the one class.