# Setting Environment Variables in Salesforce DX?

Tags: apex, unit-test, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am looking to update SFDX_IMPROVED_CODE_COVERAGE Environment variable to true. Loosely documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352942&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) and [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_sf_cli_code_coverage_apextests.htm). I am using the syntax documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_config_values.htm#topic-title) that seems to show that I can update that Environment variable with something like this:

`sfdx force:config:set improvedCodeCoverage=true`

however i get this error in the terminal: ERROR running force:config:get:  Unknown config key: improvedCodeCoverage.

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong here? coverting to camelcase seems to be what is documented

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SFDX config values and environment variable-based configuration are not *necessarily* congruent, and at least based on the documentation, it looks like these are not: you have to actually set the environment variable.

You can do that for a single command by doing

```
SFDX_IMPROVED_CODE_COVERAGE=true sfdx force:do:work ...
```

or set it for a shell session with

```
export SFDX_IMPROVED_CODE_COVERAGE=true
```

If you wish that to be permanent, set it in the config file for your shell (such as `~/.zshrc` if you use zsh).

Comment: Appreciate the answer! I'm on a Mac and zsh looks to be the default. I am a bit new to these command line shells so forgive me but I found a file named zshrc in the hidden etc folder. It says "Setup user specific overrides for this in ~/.zshrc. See zshbuiltins(1)". Where in this file should i set an environment variable? Theres Default key bindings and default prompt but no default Environment variables

Comment: If you don't have a `.zshrc` file in your home directory, you can create one. You'd then add the `export ...` line above into that file. Don't modify the one in `/etc`; that's the global zsh config.

Comment: thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables always refer to the system's environment variables, not any configuration settings in an app. You can see your current variables with `env` in any Windows shell. To set them globally, go to Win+X, System, System Info > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables..., and add a new variable there. Make sure you restart any terminals/shells for the variables to take effect. As mentioned by David, msys32/bash/zsh/etc have "rc" files that you can use to set an environment variable for a single terminal as well. Refer to the online help manual for whichever shell you're using.